# How do I resize a matplotlib line chart created from a for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a for loop that creates a multi line chart in matplotlib. I am unable to resize the chart or manipulate it using the fig.xx functions.

```py
df3=df3.tail(500)  
ax=plt.gca()  
for i in columns:  
    df3.plot(kind='line', y=i, ax=ax)  
plt.savefig('sector.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set those .figure settings before the loop like this:

```
df3=df3.tail(500)  
plt.figure(figsize=(10,2), facecolor='grey') # figure settings
ax=plt.gca()  
for i in columns:  
    df3.plot(kind='line', y=i, ax=ax)  
plt.savefig('sector.png')
```

Is this what you meant?